# JAX-WS: Remove incoming illegal null characters in XML SOAP &#x0;

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws, invalid-characters

Environment:
* JAX WS 2.2.8
* Standalone publishing with Endpoint

Problem:
 * External, non modifiable system send incoming requests with NULL (0x0) values (�)
 * jax-ws crashes, because XML unmarshalling doesn't allow NULL

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException with linked exception: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Invalid character reference: null character not allowed in XML content.

- Tried LogicalHandler and SOAPHandler, but buth crash once i try to access the message

Possible Solution:
* Need a way to access the message on a character level, so i can remove illegal chars and pass it forward.

Any ideas? Code snippets?

thanks in advance